# runtime! variable in less.sh

Tags: linux, bash, vim, ssh

Using the vim pager that comes with the program. I am trying to re-map my less.sh to run from my home directory and call the config from ~/bin. I'm getting the error:

> Error detected while processing command line: E33: No previous substitute regular expression

I think my problem is I do not understand the "runtime!" can someone explain what the "runtime!" is being used for?

This is the original lines of code from /usr/share/vim/vim72/macros/less.sh:

```
if test -t 1; then
 if test $# = 0; then
   vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' -
  else
   vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' "$@"
```

This is what I trying to do placing the less.sh in ~/bin/less.sh:

```
if test -t 1; then
 if test $# = 0; then
   vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c '~/bin/less.vim' -
  else
   vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c '~/bin/less.vim' "$@"
  fi
```

I am running the command by editing my .bashrc alias vless="~/bin/less.sh"

Comment: Nothing is going to expand the `~` in that argument. `~` is expanded by the shell in specific places (and not in single quotes). Try `-c "$HOME/bin/less.vim"` there instead and see what happens.

Comment: `runtime!` (as explained by vim in `:help :runtime` runs the ex commands from the file given as argument found in the vim `'runtimepath'`. The `!` means run all such matching files as opposed to just the first.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to use a text editor as a pager?

Answer (score 0):

Vim's `:runtime` command reads and interprets Vim commands from a file that is based on one of the directories in the `'runtimepath'` option. Since most Vimscript files either ship with Vim itself or are installed in the user's `~/.vim/` directory, that's a convenient way to invoke a script.

The command is a specialization of `:source {filespec}`, which is what you need to use; a filespec itself isn't a valid Vim command, and Vim tries to interpret it as a pattern, and stumbles across the `~` character.

```
vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c 'source ~/bin/less.vim' -
```

There's even a shortcut `-S` command-line option for that:

```
vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -S '~/bin/less.vim' -
```